# php7.4 in ubuntu 21.10: apache2 fails to start

Tags: apache2, php-7.4, ubuntu-21.04

I try to run php7.4 in ubuntu 21.10 but I get this error.

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Missing libphp7.4.so

I installed `libphp7.4-embed` but the problem persists. The files are installed in /usr/lib/ not in /usr/lib/apache2/modules/. Symbolic link did not help (`undefined symbol: php7_module`).

How to make php7.4 run in ubuntu 21.10?

I try some commands

```
$ sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm

Conf php7.4-fpm already enabled
$ sudo a2enmod php7.4-fpm

ERROR: Module php7.4-fpm does not exist!
```

Comment: Before becoming enthusiastic ... after much frustration, I just deleted `sudo rm  php7.4.load` and miracle ... it works.

Answer (score 9):

Both OP and @Andrew have pieced together a good solution, but since I just had to do this, let me put it all together, with a few extra clarification steps.

First: What version of PHP do you have now / will you use?

```
php -v
```

Returns `PHP 8.1.2` so `8.1` in my case.

Next, disable the existing apache2 module that was giving you trouble:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
```

Finally, enable the one you found above:

```
sudo a2enmod php8.1
```

Restart apache2 and you're all set.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

after much try and error:
`rm /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.load`

Now it works.

(there is only one php* in mods-enabled: `php7.4.conf`. I don't know if it matters.)

Comment: You can remove this file by the command: sudo a2dismod php7.4

Comment: @AndrewKrizhanovsky, the sudo a2dismod php7.4 did the trick on php 8.1, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to stay on php7.4, so moving to 8.1 was not an option. Line 3 of `php7.4.load` made referance to `libphp7.4.so`

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so
```

When googling, I learned that I was missing an php module. Apache2 would start after installing this.

```
sudo apt install -y libapache2-mod-php7.4
```